# npm file-saver's saveAs() working when file is transferred from localhost server but not when file is transferred from cloud machine

Tags: node.js, express, angular5

I am calling an express api which provides a xlsx file stored at express server directory for download to client from my angular 5 app.
express server response method is as follows:

`res.download(path.join(__dirname, "../../ExcelTemplate/Details.xlsx"));`

And in my angular app I am using 'file-saver' npm pkg and using saveAs function as follows:

`saveAs(response, "Details.xlsx");`

In response from server I am getting required blob object.

Now when running the express server and app on localhost and hitting the requested api I am getting the saveAS dialog box on screen(in case of firefox) and I can download the file on my machine or file gets downloaded automatically(in case of chrome). But when I deploy the app on cloud machine I am getting the blob object in response but no dialog box or no file is getting downloaded automatically.

Comment: Please add some more information regarding your problem and your reasearch on it. For example are there any error in then Inspection Console?

Comment: @Stamos no there are no errors and express's res.download() method sets the required headers and transfers the file at path to client (link to reference https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.download). I have checked all the response headers in browser's network tab and all are correct.

Comment: @Stamos On localhost all the code is working fine.I'm getting the blob object in response and passing the same in saveAs(),displays the dialog box to download the file aftr clicking the download buttn. Problem occurs when I deploy the app on cloud server and access the site from my local machine and when I click the download buttn I don't see any dialog box on my screen and no errors on console but I can see the blob object in response from the server on console.